# SCOM: How to display custom perf counters from Services

Tags: scom, system-center

I have a number of Windows Services written in .NET/C# and each of these have custom performance counters added via the System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationData and          System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationDataCollection classes.
In System Center 2012 I have a Dashboard for each of these Services in which I want to display/graph the values from my custom counters. However, I only see the standard performance counters which are the same for all Services and can not find my custom counters anywhere. My counters are visible via PerfMon but SCOM  does not see them.
Is it possible to do what I want, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the console via command prompt?
Use /clearcache when calling the exe to allow the perf data to reload.

Answer (score -1):

try using powershell script to collect your counters and submit the collected data in a property bag. it should work.